# Can't list external connections

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When trying to execute graph API /connections GET call (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/externalconnectors-externalconnection-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) both from application or from graph explorer) getting an UnknownError. The C# code for performing mentioned call from application is the following:

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "TENANT ID";
var clientId = "AZURE APP CLIENT ID";
var clientSecret = "AZURE APP SECRET";
var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var connections = await graphClient.Connections.Request().GetAsync();
```

The following exception is thrown from last line:

```
One or more errors occurred. (Code: UnknownError
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    date: 2021-10-01T11:41:46
    request-id: 1a1b9a3e-b378-45d0-8c8f-7ddc5311374c
    client-request-id: 1a1b9a3e-b378-45d0-8c8f-7ddc5311374c
    ClientRequestId: 1a1b9a3e-b378-45d0-8c8f-7ddc5311374c
)
```

Below is screenshot of same request execution from graph explorer:

[image: Graph Explorer]

Comment: How did you define scopes?

Comment: One line of code was missed ))) I have edited the code. The actual scopes are defined in target Azure AD application: ExternalConnection.ReadWrite.OwnedBy, ExternalItem.ReadWrite.All, ExternalItem.ReadWrite.OwnedBy

Answer (score 0):

External connections endpoint requires `Application` permission type. Graph Explorer is public client which uses `Delegated` permission. That's the reason why it is not working in Graph Explorer.

In your code try to use `External` connections

```
var connections = await graphClient.External.Connections.Request().GetAsync();
```

Resource:

[List external connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/externalconnectors-externalconnection-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: That's why I have also tried via application permission type (look at C# code above), however for both cases same error are occurring. About using External.Connections instead of just Connections: External.Connections is from beta version of Graph API and it just returns empty array. In v1.0 the correct version according to Microsoft documentation is Connections (and not External.Connections).

Comment: One more thing: In documentation near Delegated permission type it is written "Not Applicable", which makes me guess, that possibly it also supported for Delegated permission type, because for other calls when some permission type is not supported, documentation says "Not Supported" and not "Not Applicable".

Answer (score 0):

For your Get query in https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer, change the following:

```
To: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/external/connections/connectionName
From: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/connections
```